# Область видимости JS

Tags: наследование, javascript

В чем разница между

```
foo = new(function foo(){
    this.v = 2;
    this.bar={
       init:function(){return foo.v}
    }
})
```

и

```
foo = new(function foo(){
    this.v = 2
});
foo.bar={
   init:function(){return foo.v}
}
```

в первом варианте foo.bar.init() возвращает undefined, во втором 2.

Вывод консоли:

```
foo1
foo1 {v: 2, bar: Object}
bar: Object
init: function (){return foo1.v}
v: 2

foo2
foo2 {v: 2, bar: Object}
bar: Object
init: function (){return foo2.v}
v: 2

foo2.bar.init();
2

foo1.bar.init();
undefined

foo1.bar.init
function (){return foo1.v}

foo2.bar.init
function (){return foo2.v}

foo2.bar
Object {init: function}

foo1.bar
Object {init: function}
```

Comment: странное здесь только то, что область видимости в которой видно имя функции определилась круглыми скобками http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SaF7d/ и даже так: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SaF7d/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression)

There is a distinction between the function name and the variable the function is assigned to:

1. The function name cannot be changed, while the variable the function is assigned to can be reassigned.
2. The function name can be used **only within the function's body**. Attempting to use it outside the function's body results in an error (or undefined if the function name was previously declared via a var statement). For example:

---

```
var y = function x() {};
alert(x); // throws an error
```

The function name also appears when the function is serialized via Function's toString method.

Касательно вашего вопроса - как я уже показал, извне доступа к foo() в первом случае нет вообще, следовательно вы его объявляете присваиванием, с другой стороны внутри функции у вас идет запрос к foo(), которая ещё всего лишь функция, а не объект foo, естественно  foo.v - undefined.

[примеры](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/SaF7d/5/)

```
function test1() {
    var foo = new(
      function foo() {            // foo  ----+
        this.v = 2;               //          |
        this.bar = {              //          |
            init: function () {   //          |
                return foo.v      // foo <----+
            }
      }
    });
    console.log(foo.bar.init()); //undefined
}

function test2() {
    function foo() {
        this.v = 2;
    }
    console.log(foo.v); //undefined
    foo();
    console.log(foo.v); //undefined (потому что контекст foo() - не foo)
    console.log(this, this.v); //window,2 - объявили глобальный v=2 (контекст foo () - window
}

function test3() {
    var bar = new(function foo() {
        //это конструктор, он выполняется при new
        this.v = 2;
    });
    console.log(bar.v); //2
}

function test4() {
    function foo() {
        //это конструктор, он выполняется при new
        this.v = 2;
    }
    foo.prototype.getv = function () {
        return this.v;
    }
    var bar = new(foo);
    console.log(bar.v, bar.getv()); //2,2
}

function test5() {
    var foo = new(
      function foo() {
        var that=this;
        this.v = 2;            
        this.bar = {           
            init: function () {
                return that.v; //that потому что иначе контекст будет bar                
            }
      }
    });
    console.log(foo.bar.init()); //2
}

console.log('==1==');
test1();
console.log('==2==');
test2();
console.log('==3==');
test3();
console.log('==4==');
test4();
console.log('==5==');
test5();
```